# Return List of integers from one String consisting of numbers and commas

Tags: flutter, dart

Dart/Flutter:

I have one string that contains integers, spaces, and maybe commas. How do I convert this to a list of integers?

Example: `var StringOfNumbers =` one of these strings:

```
'1, 2, 4, 7,'
'1, 2, 4 7'
'1 2 4 7'
```

After conversion, all should output to
`[1,2,4,7]`

I've played with map, parse, and split but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try this

```
final string = '1, 2, 4, 7, 1, 2, 4 7 1 2 4 7';
final list = string.split(' ').map((p) => int.tryParse(p.replaceAll(',', '')) ?? 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  var string = '1, 2, 4, 7,';
  var matches = RegExp(r'\d+').allMatches(string);

  var myList = matches.map<int>((e) => int.parse(e.group(0))).toList();
  print(myList);
}
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 4, 7]
```